# knockout mapping, initial values and computed ones

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I been building the model system, when it occurred that I might make my life easier by using mapping plugin, though I'm facing few problems.

The thing is that I don't have a data at the initialization moment, but I still want to provide empty properties to the screen. I made that possible by defining the model at the initialization and later on updating model with values.

```
App.Models.User = {
    name: null,
    username: null,
    gender: null,
    email: null,
    img: null
};
var me = ko.mapping.fromJS(App.Models.User);
```

That worked quite well, though I'm not sure is this is the best way to accomplish the task.

But now I want to update the `img` property, I'm not sure yet if I want to create a new property from it or have that property updated itself, would like to know how can be done both scenarios.

My data from server looks somewhat like this

```
{"me":
    {
        "username"      :"john",
        "email"         :"johndoe@gmail.com",
        "name"          :"John Doe",
        "gender"        :"male",
        "img"           :"profile_img_john.jpg"
    }
}
```

I want update img or create a new property from it and make it `images/profile_img_john.jpg`

Hope all that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would split knockout view model creation and initialization parts. It will let you create view model without any real data first, bind it to HTML, and then update with real data.

See example I created for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/apuchkov/zscP2/

```
var data = { "me":
    {
        "username"      :"john",
        "email"         :"johndoe@gmail.com",
        "name"          :"John Doe",
        "gender"        :"male",
        "img"           :"profile_img_john.jpg"
    }
} 

var User = function(data) {
     this.name = ko.observable();
     this.username = ko.observable();
     this.gender = ko.observable();
     this.email = ko.observable();
     this.img = ko.observable();

     this.update(data);
 };

ko.utils.extend(User.prototype, {
    update: function(data) {
        this.name(data.name || "");
        this.username(data.username || "");
        this.gender(data.gender || "");
        this.email(data.email || "");
        this.img(data.img || "default-image-url.png");
    }
});

//firstly create viewmodel without any data
var user = new User({});
ko.applyBindings(user);

//then set data later 
user.update(data.me);
```

Comment: Well I'm using something very similar, except that I created one abstract update function for all models, which does the job, but my aim was to find out if it is possible to prevent defining models and use `ko.mapping` plugin which would define models based on data from server. I guess that's not really possible if you don't have any data at the beginning, which quite makes sense but also takes away big part of benefits I expected from `ko.mapping`, anwyay, because there was no answers for a while, I'll mark yours as accepted.